# Как можно сократить время компиляции в c++

Tags: c++, математика, прогрессия

Я написал программу и начал проверять ее. У нее стоит условие, что время выполнения меньше 1 секунды. И проверяю на сайте компилятора, понял, что наверное ошибка состоит в том, что при постановке больших чисел, программа компилируется дольше. Что подскажете, может нужно сократить код, или как-то что-то сделать?

```
  #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   int main(){

   int a,b,s=0,u=0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    for (int i=a;i<=b;i++){
     if (i%2==0){
     u+=i;
     } 
      else{
       s+=i;
        }
         } 
         cout<<u-s;
        return 0;
         }
```

Сама программа заключается в том, что вы вводете два числа и суммируются четные и нечетные от первого ввода до второго а в конце вычитается из четный нечетные. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: время выполнения или компиляции сократить то нужно?

Comment: При чем тут время компиляции? `a` и `b` неизвестны на этапе компиляции, они вводятся при выполнении.

Comment: Просто написано ограничение времени. Скорее всего время выполнения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, вам нужно это:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    if (a > b) { int t = a; a = b; b = t; }
    cout << (a+b-(b%2)*(1+2*b)+(a%2)*(1-2*a))/2 << endl;
}
```

Время компиляции никакого значения не имеет, только время счета. А теперь прикиньте количество вычислений в вашей программе при значениях, скажем, 1 и 1000000000...

Comment: Спасибо, и в правду работает

Comment: Вас это удивляет? :) Кстати, если ответ вас устраивает - принимайте его, птичка слева...